# Best Java List implementation to return for an empty List?

Tags: java, list

Many times I'm operating in a function that returns a List type. For many types of errors or certain inputs it is invalid just to return an empty list which I normally do with the following:

```
return new ArrayList<DataType>();
```

Is that the best way or is there a better implementation of the List Interface to use for this situation? I should clarify that by "best" way I'm thinking from a performance perspective. I realize that any gains would be rather trivial but the OCD side of me is curious.

Comment: What does OCD stands for? Curious here too =)

Comment: @BonanzaOne Obsessive Compulsive Disorder.

Answer (score 14):

There is a method of `Collections` specifically for this: [`Collections.emptyList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()). This will return an empty, immutable List. You could replace the line in your code with this equivalent:

```
return Collections.<DataType>emptyList();
```

Comment: As of 1.7- I didn't need to parameterize the return type. That is, 
`return new Collections.emptyList()` 
did not generate a warning.

Comment: @IcedDante Yes, you shouldn't need to most of the time—the compiler will figure it out for you. I just specified it explicitly for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @IcedDante Emphasizing: it wil return an **immutable** List. For example, you will get an Exception if you try to add something to the list.